# How to bind data from join query in FirebaseListAdapter?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to populate ListView using FirebaseListAdapter.
I've added the following listener to join data:

```
mWODsReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            final String wod_key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            System.out.println("The wod key is " + wod_key);
            mDatabase.child("wod_rounds/" + wod_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        modelWODRound post = postSnapshot.getValue(modelWODRound.class);
                        String round_key = postSnapshot.getKey();
                        System.out.println("Round key and time cap are " + round_key + ": " + post.getRoundlimit().toString());
                        DatabaseReference refRE = mDatabase.child("round_exercises").child(round_key);
                        refRE.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String exercise_key = postSnapshot.getKey();
                                    System.out.println("Round exercises are " + exercise_key);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I can see that println is showing me right values.
How can I bind strings round_key and exercise_key to fields of android.R.layout.two_line_list_item?

Comment: To populate data in ListView you should create a layout for the list and an adapter. There are many examples in SO, so it won't be difficult. Also I want to suggest you to change your variable names using CamelCase. Like round_key be roundKey and exercise_key be exerciseKey. First character is in lower case.

Comment: @JaniceKartika the question is mostly about how to send those joined values  from DatabaseReference to FirebaseListAdapter. Once they are in adapter, there is no problem in binding them to specific textviews of item layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create custom class for the adapter :

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomItem> {

public ListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.two_line_list_item, null);
    }

    CustomItem p = getItem(position);
    if (p != null) {
            TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.round_key);
            TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.exercise_key);


            if (tt2 != null) {
                tt2.setText(p.getRoundKey());
            }

            if (tt3 != null) {
                tt3.setText(p.getExerciseKey());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

custom Item class :

```
public class CustomItem {

    public String round_key;
    public String exercuse_key;

    public CustomItem() {

    }

    public CustomItem(String r_key, String e_key)
    {
        this.round_key=r_key;
        this.exercise_key=e_key;
    }

    public String getRoundKey(){
        return this.round_key;
    }

    public String getExerciseKey(){
        return this.exercise_key;
    }
}
```

On MainActivity :

```
private List<CustomItem> customItem;
private ListAdapter adapter;
private CustomItem mItem;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

    customItem = new ArrayList<CustomItem>();

    getFirebaseData();

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void getFirebaseData(){
        mWODsReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            final String wod_key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            System.out.println("The wod key is " + wod_key);
            mDatabase.child("wod_rounds/" + wod_key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        modelWODRound post = postSnapshot.getValue(modelWODRound.class);
                        String round_key = postSnapshot.getKey();
                        System.out.println("Round key and time cap are " + round_key + ": " + post.getRoundlimit().toString());
                        DatabaseReference refRE = mDatabase.child("round_exercises").child(round_key);
                        refRE.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                    String exercise_key = postSnapshot.getKey();
                                    System.out.println("Round exercises are " + exercise_key);
                                    mItem = new CustomItem(round_key,exercise_key);
                                    customItem.add(mItem);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```