# Firebase UI - add data from different database children to android application

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I want to add specific data from different children of Firebase realtime database to my android application.

My realtime database

[image]

now i want to get course from **courses**

[image: (child) courses]

name from **rooms**

[image: (child) rooms]

name from **teachers**

[image: (child) teachers]

and add it **recyclerview** in my application

my **MainActivity.java**

```
private RecyclerView rvTimeTable;
private TableAdapter tableAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_time_table);

    initVariables();

    rvTimeTable.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TimeTable> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<TimeTable>()
                    .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("teachers"), TimeTable.class)
                    .build();

    tableAdapter = new TableAdapter(options);
    rvTimeTable.setAdapter(tableAdapter);
}

private void initVariables() {
    rvTimeTable = findViewById(R.id.rv_time_table);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    tableAdapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    tableAdapter.stopListening();
}
```

**adapter class**

```
public class TableAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TimeTable, TableViewHolder> {
    /***
     * Initialize a {@link RecyclerView.Adapter} that listens to a Firebase query. See
     * {@link FirebaseRecyclerOptions} for configuration options.
     *
     * @param options
     */
    public TableAdapter(@NonNull FirebaseRecyclerOptions<TimeTable> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull TableViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull TimeTable model) {
        holder.tvTime.setText(model.getTime());
        holder.tvSubject.setText(model.getSubject());
        holder.tvRoom.setText(model.getRoom());
        holder.tvTeacher.setText(model.getTeacher());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public TableViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.table_design, parent, false);
        return new TableViewHolder(view);
    }
}

class TableViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tvTime, tvSubject, tvRoom, tvTeacher;

    public TableViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
        tvSubject = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_subject);
        tvRoom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_room);
        tvTeacher = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_teacher);
    }
}
```

**model class**

```
public class TimeTable {

    private String time, subject, room, teacher;

    public TimeTable() {
        time = "00:00";
        subject = "subject";
        room = "room";
        teacher = "teacher";
    }

    public TimeTable(String time, String subject, String room, String teacher) {
        this.time = time;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.room = room;
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getRoom() {
        return room;
    }

    public void setRoom(String room) {
        this.room = room;
    }

    public String getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }

    public void setTeacher(String teacher) {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    }
}
```

**[my current output]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tF1e.jpg)

i just want repective data from the database to be shown in here

I tried to use **SnapShotParser** but i can't figure out how this works (if it works).

```
...setQuery(..., new SnapshotParser<Chat>() {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Chat parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        return ...;
    }
});
```

Comment: Inside database there are more stuff, but i only require whats asked in the question.

Comment: Nothing is built in for such joins. Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41690136 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/34561726? In that last one I show how you can just load the additional data and then set it to the holder asynchronously. I do recommend denormalizing your data though, as (even on RTDBs web socket connection) this number of calls will start adding up. Also see: [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).